# Install a wheel package inside a docker container

Tags: docker, pip, installation, airflow

I am creating an airflow docker container using the docker image "puckel/docker-airflow".
I have created a docker-compose file that uses this image and links 2 volumes, one for dags and other for the wheel package.

When I start the container and go to airflow UI it throws "No module named 'custPkg'" error. So I exec into the container using the command
`docker exec -ti <container_id> bash`
and then installed it using pip. I can use the package if I run a python shell using the command
`from custPkg.abc import Base`
but it's still not working on the airflow.

The airflow webserver which even refreshes after some time is still showing the same error on the terminal on which I started the conatainer using
`docker-compose up`

my docker-compose file looks like this

```
version: "3"

services:
  webserver:
    image: puckel/docker-airflow:latest
    container_name: test_container
    volumes:
      - /home/ubuntu/dags1/:/usr/local/airflow/dags
      - /home/ubuntu/dist/:/usr/local/airflow/dist
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    restart: always
```

## --------------------NEW UPDATE----------------------------

I just restarted the container and it is working now, but I don't want to go into the container and run the exec command manually. Can I somehow do this using the docker-compose file only?

Comment: Do you have a custom `Dockerfile` you can add to the question?  (If you install packages using a `docker exec` shell, they'll get lost as soon as the container exits.)

Comment: I do not have a docker file I am just using the docker-compose file mentioning the docker image